# How to send email notification to subscribers when adding file programmatically to document and media folder in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have more than one user having admin roles who are subscribed to a common folder which store some sort of images and documents. When one user add some images in the folder a notification email is sent to the subscribed user who has the view permission.
My Problem starts from here when I upload the images through the portal, email notification is sent successfully. But when I try to save the image using the following code the email notification is not send.

**

```
_dlAppLocalService.addFileEntry(userId, companyGroup.getGroupId(), folder.getFolderId(), fileName,
ContentTypes.TEXT_CSV_UTF8, fileContent.getBytes(), serviceContext);
```

**

For further explanation :- This particular code is triggered inside the Schedular so I'm creating ServiceContext as follows:-

```
long companyId = _portal.getDefaultCompanyId();

Company company = _companyLocalService.getCompany(companyId);
Group companyGroup = _groupLocalService.getCompanyGroup(companyId);
User defaultUser = company.getDefaultUser();

long userId = defaultUser.getUserId();
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
serviceContext.setUserId(userId);
```

and then passing service context inside the above method.
I found that request and themeDisplay are coming as null in **com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.DLImpl.startWorkflowInstance(long, DLFileVersion, String, ServiceContext)** which leads to blankEntryURL and **com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.notifySubscribers(long, FileVersion, String, ServiceContext**) method fails to execute.

Can anyone help?. How I can get the file entryURL without having objects of themeDisplay and request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid blank `entryURL` adding the line below before the call to `addFileEntry()`:

```
serviceContext.setAttribute("entryURL", "anyNotEmptyURL");
```

But it is not enough for the method `notifySubscribers()` to run to the end. You need to add another line of code:

```
serviceContext.setCommand(Constants.ADD);
```

Unless a proper command value, the notification will be aborted.

Comment: Hi Sébastien Le Marchand thanks for the reply. I ended up doing this only.

Comment: Hi @KratiyagGupta. If you think my answer is right, could you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it?